# How to compare the date strings and Grouping the date strings in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, compare, grouping, nsdate

I have one array and it contains the date strings. I want to compare the date strings and displayed the date string as grouping, so it should display the date as only once, when duplicate date as found.

My array

```
 NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"2010-12-28 04:23:47",
                       @"2010-12-28 04:21:50",
                       @"2010-12-28 04:18:56",
                       @"2010-12-27 13:39:18",
                       @"2010-12-22 21:48:09",
                       @"2010-12-22 20:44:18",
                       @"2010-12-22 20:25:26",
                       @"2010-12-22 20:08:39",nil];
```

Expected Output is,

```
"2010-12-28 "
"2010-12-27 "
"2010-12-22 ".
```

When compared to the date string, the time is not a problem, i want to display the date wise only(Grouping date).

Please help me out.

THanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code as follows,

```
NSMutableArray *filterdArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(NSString *string in arr)
{
 NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
 //Check that date is present in filterdArray
 //if not present
 //add the value to array using
 [filterdArray addObject:[components objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

Then sort the values in `filterdArray`